# How do I make Sendchamp Voice text to speech API call user with local number?

Tags: mobile, sms, voice

I am integrating Sendchamp Voice API and I want it to call the user in the user's local number and not a US or Canadian number. How do I do that?

Comment: https://sendchamp.com

Comment: What do you mean by "in the user's local number"?   Do you mean that the caller ID should show the number of the person you are calling?